# angular 12 decode jwt token with this.userService.getUser(this.authService.decodedToken.nameid)

Tags: angular, jwt, angular12

Hi before angular 12 I use this.userService.getUser(this.authService.decodedToken.nameid) but in angular 12 my token wasn’t decoded what can I do

I have user.service.ts file (

```
updateUser(id: number, user: User) {
  return this.http.put(this.baseUrl + 'users/' + id, user);
}
```

)
and in my profile userEdit.component.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class MemberEditResolver implements Resolve<User> {
  constructor(
    private userService: UserService,
    private router: Router,
    private alertify: AlertifyService,
    private authService: AuthService
  ) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<User | any> {
    return this.userService.getUser(this.authService.decodedToken.nameid).pipe(
      catchError(error => {
        this.alertify.error('Problem retrieving your data');
        this.router.navigate(['/home']);
        return of(null);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

in my Resolver

```
@Injectable()
export class MemberEditResolver implements Resolve<User> {
  constructor(
    private userService: UserService,
    private router: Router,
    private alertify: AlertifyService,
    private authService: AuthService
  ) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<User | any> {
    return this.userService.getUser(this.authService.decodedToken.nameid).pipe(
      catchError(error => {
        this.alertify.error('Problem retrieving your data');
        this.router.navigate(['/home']);
        return of(null);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

I also add my resolver in my angular Routes

```
{path: 'startup-edit', component: StartupEditComponent,resolve: {user: MemberEditResolver}},
```

and this is my authservice

```
login(model: any) {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'login', model).pipe(
      map((response: any) => {
        const user = response;
        if (user) {
          localStorage.setItem('token', user.token);
          localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user.user));
          this.decodedToken = this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(user.token);
          this.currentUser = user.user;
          // this.userid = this.decodedToken.userid;
          this.changeMemberPhoto(this.currentUser.photoUrl);
        }
      })
    );
  }

  register(user: User) {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'register', user);
  }

  loggedIn() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    return !this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token!);
  }
```

Comment: Share your `authservice` as well

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal tnx i almost forget that service

Comment: What is `jwtHelper` and what is the error you are getting now